# Umbraco 7 access rights at property level

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I don't think this can be done out of the box, but is there any way of protecting certain properties or whole tabs of properties in the CMS so only editors with selected roles or rights could edit them, and standard users could not (although they could happily edit other non-protected properties).

We want to protect certain content from accidental changes.

To clarify : protect some of the content on a document, not whole documents.

Is this possible?

I would rather this was done at the server level (rather than a javascript bodge to hide the tab/properties).

Comment: Do you need to do this for a specific property type or a number of properties?

Comment: Preferably a number of properties

Answer (score 0):

For now the only way to achieve something like this serverside, would be to add listeners to the ContentService save events and then check if they have tried changing any of the protected properties and then cancel the save if so.

Combining this with some kind of frontend javascript approach would most likely be best though, so the user actually knows why, when they are not permitted to save a document.

You may also be able to do something like, looping through the protected properties before the save happens and revert any potential changes back to the base document if they aren't permitted to change the property. I guess this would allow the users to actually save the document with their changes (just without the changes they made to protected properties).

Documentation on ContentService events:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/events/contentservice-events